# Generating compilation report with gwt:compileReport

Tags: gwt, report, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate a compilation report from my maven-gwt project.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport) site i should see the generated reports in the generated sources folder. However when i run either of those:

`mvn gwt:compile-report`,
`mvn gwt:compile-report -DcompileReport`,
`mvn gwt:compile-report -DcompileReport=true`,
`mvn gwt:compile-report -DcompileReport=Test`

I get:

`[WARNING] No compile reports found, did you compile with compileReport option set ?`

In my `pom.xml` file i set the reporting stuff as:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>Report</id>
                <reports>
                    <report>Test</report>
                </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

**EDIT:**

Pom changed to:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>test</goal>
          <goal>i18n</goal>
          <goal>generateAsync</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
          <compileReports>true</compileReports>
          <sources>
            <source>target/generated-sources/gwt</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, -->
    <!--see gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
    <configuration>
      <runTarget>Bondegard.html</runTarget>
      <compileReports>true</compileReports>
      <logLevel>SPAM</logLevel>
      <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
      <i18nMessagesBundle>pl.spot.bondegard.bondegard.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And still have no reports. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compile report is created during a build (`gwt:compile` with the [compile report activated](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compileReport)), `gwt:compile-report` only publishes it into your Maven site.

Comment: Okay. I tried it, but while compiling with gwt:compile, the compiler doesn't see, nor generate the Async Interfaces. When i do gwt:run the compilation passes, but the reports aren't generated then.

Comment: `gwt:compile` only calls the GWT compile, if you want to generate _async_ interfaces from _sync_ ones for GWT-RPC, then you also need `gwt:generateAsync`; configure your POM accordingly.

Comment: I changed the `pom.xml`. What am i missing?

Comment: `<compileReport>`, not `<compileReports>`